# What is the purpose of not allowing to use a function call as a default value?

Tags: php

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) says:

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call.

Could you explain **the purpose** of not allowing to use a function call (or others) as a default value?

P.S.: actually it's possible to call built-in functions, **like array()**, but **not self-constructed**

**UPD:** [array is not a regular function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php):

> array() is a language construct used to represent literal arrays, and
>   not a regular function.

Comment: No, `array()` is not a function, it’s a “language construct.”

Comment: @CBroe You are right. It's my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's less of a *"purpose"* and more of a technical limitation.

The default value is established by the parser while the source code is being parsed. The value must be something which is available at parse time and which the parser can interpret; i.e. it must not depend on runtime information (no variables which only exist at runtime, no other functions which may or may not be defined later) and cannot be an expression the parser cannot evaluate (compound expressions that need to be evaluated, no function calls which need a runtime). That mostly leaves you with simple literals like strings, numbers and array literals.